# How to execute functions in javascript?

Tags: javascript

below is an example of reading array of objects using **myFunction()**. '**myFunction()**' is executing properly but **myJSON()** not. how can i read  **myJSON()**??

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="id01"></div>
<script>
function myFunction(arr) {
    var out = "";
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        out += '<a href="' + arr[i].url + '">' +
        arr[i].display + '</a><br>';
    }
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
</script>

<script src="http://www.mybeautiful.net63.net/test/json-tutorials/json-example.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

`json-example.js` contains:

```
myFunction([
{
"display": "HTML Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp"
},
{
"display": "CSS Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp"
},
{
"display": "JavaScript Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp"
},
{
"display": "jQuery Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp"
},
{
"display": "JSON Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/json/default.asp"
},
{
"display": "AJAX Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp"
},
{
"display": "SQL Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp"
},
{
"display": "PHP Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp"
},
{
"display": "XML Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/default.asp"
}
])

myJSON([
{
"display": "HTML Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp"
},
{
"display": "CSS Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp"
},
{
"display": "JavaScript Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp"
},
{
"display": "jQuery Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp"
},
{
"display": "JSON Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/json/default.asp"
},
{
"display": "AJAX Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp"
},
{
"display": "SQL Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp"
},
{
"display": "PHP Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp"
},
{
"display": "XML Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/default.asp"
}
])
```

Comment: You're calling a function called `myJSON`, but you haven't defined it anywhere. Where's the code for `myJSON`?

Comment: @smarx Where is the call to `myJSON()`? Did he edit the question so soon after posting that it doesn't show up in the edit history?

Comment: @Barmar It's in the script brought in via the `<script>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="id01"></div>
<div id="id02"></div>
<script>

    function myJSON(arr) {
        var out = "";
        var i;
        for(i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            out += '<a href="' + arr[i].url + '">' +
            arr[i].display + '</a><br>';
        }
        document.getElementById("id02").innerHTML = out;
    }

</script>

<script src="http://www.mybeautiful.net63.net/test/json-tutorials/json-example.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
    
    function myFunction(arr) {
        var out = "";
        var i;
        for(i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            out += '<a href="' + arr[i].url + '">' +
            arr[i].display + '</a><br>';
        }
        document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
    }
    
    function myJSON(arr) {
        var out = "";
        var i;
        for(i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            out += '<a href="' + arr[i].url + '">' +
            arr[i].display + '</a><br>';
        }
        document.getElementById("id02").innerHTML = out;
    }
   myFunction([
{
"display": "HTML Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp"
},
{
"display": "CSS Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp"
},
{
"display": "JavaScript Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp"
},
{
"display": "jQuery Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp"
},
{
"display": "JSON Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/json/default.asp"
},
{
"display": "AJAX Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp"
},
{
"display": "SQL Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp"
},
{
"display": "PHP Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp"
},
{
"display": "XML Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/default.asp"
}
])

myJSON([
{
"display": "HTML Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp"
},
{
"display": "CSS Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp"
},
{
"display": "JavaScript Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp"
},
{
"display": "jQuery Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp"
},
{
"display": "JSON Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/json/default.asp"
},
{
"display": "AJAX Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp"
},
{
"display": "SQL Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp"
},
{
"display": "PHP Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp"
},
{
"display": "XML Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/default.asp"
}
])
```

```html
<div id="id01"></div>
 <div id="id02"></div>
```

Comment: i want to execute only **myJSON**. execution for only **myJSON** not working. I can have multiple functions in **json-example.js** . check for only **myJSON** function. its not working

Comment: Dude, As Other people mentioned as well to call a function you have to first define the function. Just calling the function is not enough. The way you are myFunction(array) is defined you have to define myJson as well.

Comment: check this [code](http://www.mybeautiful.net63.net/test/json-tutorials/json-example.js)

Comment: i have already define inside [json-example.js](http://www.mybeautiful.net63.net/test/json-tutorials/json-example.js)

Comment: Buddy, the thing in the file is the call to the function. but you have to define the function before calling.